# How to pass a pointer from C# to native function in DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

This is the signature of my function in DLL:

```
int __stdcall myFun( void * const context, const char * const pszFileName, const unsigned int buffSize, void * const pWaveFormatex );
```

All parameters are [in]. The user should pass a pointer to a `WAVEFORMATEX` struct through the last parameter. Upon return, it will be filled. All that works very well in C++.

Now, I'm trying for days to use the same DLL from C# and it simply doesn't work. The problem is in the last parameter. Since I do not know C# at all, I would like to ask somebody if this is doable at all. If it is, I would appreciate an example.

One of my last attempts was this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct WAVEFORMATEX
{
    public ushort wFormatTag;
    public ushort nChannels;
    public uint nSamplesPerSec;
    public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
    public ushort nBlockAlign;
    public ushort wBitsPerSample;
    public ushort cbSize;
}
```

Note: I also built my DLL written in C++ with the Struct Member Alignment = 1. Maybe I'm stupid, but I thought that `Pack = 1` above is related with that in C++, but I have no idea if it is...

```
[DllImport("myLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int myFun( IntPtr context,
                                        [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]
                                        string pszFileName,
                                        int bufferSize,
                                        ref IntPtr pWfx );

IntPtr unmanaged_pWfx = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WAVEFORMATEX)));

result = DLLWrapper.myFun(context,
                          "C:\\video.wmv",
                          176400,
                          ref unmanaged_pWfx );

WAVEFORMATEX wfxFormat = (WAVEFORMATEX)Marshal.PtrToStructure( unmanaged_pWfx, typeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
```

The behavior is undefined. Sometimes it hangs, sometimes it terminates... Something is very wrong. However, the problem is not in the DLL, the problem is on the C# side. Is C# capable of working with pointers at all?

Thanks for any feedback you provide.

EDIT (working C++ code):

```
void * context;
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
int success = getContext( &context );
success = myFun( context, "C:\\video.wmv", 176400, &wfx );
```

The equivalent in C# is:

```
IntPtr context;
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;

int success = getContext( out context );
success = myFun( context, "C:\\video.wmv", 176400, out wfx );


extern "C" __stdcall int getContext( void ** pContext );

[DllImport("myLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int getContext(out IntPtr context);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, based on the information you have provided I would say that you need to declare the C# function like this:

```
[DllImport("myLib.dll")]
public static extern int myFun(
    IntPtr context,
    string fileName,
    uint bufferSize,
    out WAVEFORMATEX wfx
);
```

And call the function like this:

```
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
int result = DLLWrapper.myFun(context, @"C:\video.wmv", 176400, out wfx);
```

There's really no need for manual marshalling of this struct. It's a very simple blittable struct and it is much cleaner to let the framework handle the marshalling.

I am assuming that you are accurate when you state that the final struct parameter does not need to be initialised and its members are filled out by the function.

Packing looks reasonable. I don't think you need to build your DLL in any special way. I hope that you are picking up `WAVEFORMATEX` from the Windows header files and they already specify packing for that struct.

If you are still stuck then you should show the successful C++ calling code.

---

Judging from the comments, you still have a bug somewhere in your code. In such a situation, especially when you doubt the interop, it pays to make a simple reproduction to determine whether the interop is the problem, or not. Here is mine:

**C++ DLL**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall myFun(void * const context, 
    const char * const pszFileName, const unsigned int buffSize, 
    void * const pWaveFormatex)
{
    std::cout << context << std::endl
        << pszFileName << std::endl 
        << buffSize << std::endl;

    WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
    wfx.cbSize = 1;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = 2;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = 3;
    wfx.nChannels = 4;
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 5;
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 6;
    wfx.wFormatTag = 7;
    CopyMemory(pWaveFormatex, &wfx, sizeof(wfx));

    return 666;
}
```

**C# console app**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct WAVEFORMATEX
        {
            public ushort wFormatTag;
            public ushort nChannels;
            public uint nSamplesPerSec;
            public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
            public ushort nBlockAlign;
            public ushort wBitsPerSample;
            public ushort cbSize;
        }

        [DllImport(@"Win32Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "?myFun@@YGHQAXQBDI0@Z")]
        public static extern int myFun(
            IntPtr context,
            string fileName,
            uint bufferSize,
            out WAVEFORMATEX wfx
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
            int result = myFun((IntPtr)42, @"C:\video.wmv", 176400, out wfx);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.cbSize);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.nBlockAlign);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.nChannels);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.nSamplesPerSec);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.wBitsPerSample);
            Console.WriteLine(wfx.wFormatTag);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0000002A
C:\video.wmv
176400
666
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: It hangs now. myFun will simply call `CopyMemory` and fill the `wfx` passed by the caller. Regarding packing, I reverted to 'Default', because that was a desperate move. Btw, do I have to call new in C# while creating an instance of WAVEFORMATEX?

Comment: @CodesInChaos No. That's the default.

Comment: @user3104842 Then your C++ code is not as you describe. Why is the final parameter `void*`? You say that the final parameter is pointer to `WAVEFORMATEX`. That's how `out WAVEFORMATEX` is marshaled. Show the C++ code that works.

Comment: `CopyMemory( pWfx, pWfx_, sizeof( WAVEFORMATEX ) );` There is no problem here.

Comment: No. Show the C++ code that calls the function. Or show the implementation of the function. Where you said, " All that works very well in C++." Well, show that. Show C++ code that calls this function.

Comment: The code in my answer for sure matches the information that you have provided. Something else that we cannot see is the problem.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the other functions? Like get context?

Comment: It works... don't know why it works now. The major difference is your suggestion of declaring the last parameter as `out`. Thank you!!

Comment: OK. That was there in revision 1 of course. The other answer is accurate too, but it's just easier the way I describe above.

Comment: @user3104842 No. This is perfectly possible. Blame your code and not C#. What you are attempting is certainly possible.

Comment: I guess I need some not very well documented C# stuff, because C++ part is 10000000000000000000000000000% correctly implemented. There is no doubt about that.

Comment: The C# code in my answer for sure matches the C++ code in your question. So something else is awry. You need to stop looking for limitations of C# and concentrate on what is wrong with your code. First up write a simple test C++ DLL and get that to work.

Comment: Might I ask again about the use of `void*` as your parameter. As written you C++ code that calls the function would not compile. You would need to cast `&wfx` to `void*`. Which you don't do. So I think you are not telling the whole story.

Comment: I tried to explain that simple CopyMemory is on the other side. Code that passed extensive testing and it runs 24/7 on I do not know how many machines. It's being used from C++, but now it doesn't work from C#. That tells me that the problem is in C#.

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference in void* and non void* passed to CopyMemory()?

Comment: It's just that when I build a DLL with a function that does what you describe, it works fine. I do have a deal of experience with C++/C# interop. Try and work with me.

Comment: `CopyMemory` is not what I'm looking at. I'm looking at `myFun`. You claim that to have a final parameter with type `void*`. But then you pass `WAVEFORMATEX*` and that would be a compile error in C++. So what does your C++ function really look like?

Comment: No, that's not true. In C++ you can pass any pointer to a function taking a void*. On the other hand, I have no idea what's in the C# black box regarding this subject. Since you bring it up all the time, probably C# handles that in a different way?

Comment: You are right. It's the other way around where C and C++ differ. Cannot convert from `void*` to other typed pointer.

Comment: Anyway, I'm sitting here with a test DLL that proves that the code in the answer works fine. Do you want to see it? Or do you still think that C# cannot handle this.

Comment: I have no idea how to provide to you some usable information that would help you in finding the problem. No idea what are the pitfalls in the managed world, etc...

Comment: @user3104842 My latest update provides a complete reproduction that proves that the interop is fine. Your problem is in code that I cannot see. Try stripping your project down to the bare minimum to reproduce the fault.

Comment: If you are experienced in that, I believe you it works... I mean, I don't have any reason not to believe it...

Comment: I see your edit. Surely I answered your original question. Please ask a new question. I reverted your edit here. When you have a new question, you have to ask it as  a new question.

Comment: It's still there in the edit history. You can rescue the content to a new question. But it's not fair to keep asking more and more questions in the same place. Has to be a new question. Let me know and I'll try to help you there too!

Comment: Actually, the other question is easy. Remove `out` from the two `StringBuilder` parameters. When passing `NULL`, pass C# `null`. Once you know how big to make the buffers, make sure the string builders are allocated before calling with suitably sized buffers. And that should be it.

Comment: The point is that `StringBuilder` is already a reference since it is a C# class. So it is marshalled as a pointer. `StringBuilder` marshalling is special though, but as a rule of thumb, a `class` is marshalled as a reference, a `struct` as a value.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I just created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600061/how-to-convert-c-function-signature-to-c-sharp-and-call-that-function-in-the-nat You already provided half of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is passing the IntPtr.  You're passing stack allocated variable(the one that holds actual pointer) to your code, but you want to pass the pointer. Just remove the "ref" keyword from your code.

Comment: Just did. The program terminates after `myFun` call. Btw all this marshalling stuff, is that correct at all?